# Video player that displays multiple (3 or more) subtitle tracks at once

Tags: windows, video, media-player

I'm looking for a video player that has an option to display multiple subtitles simultaneously.

It needs to run on Windows 8.1 and I don't care about the price.

---

### Illustrative Example

If you don't understand what I mean, this is an illustrative example of exactly what I need:

Let's consider that I've these files in the same folder:

- Movie.mkv (Have embedded subtitle Movie.sub1)
- Movie.sub2.srt
- Movie.sub3.srt
- Movie.sub4.srt

Let's consider that I want to load the four subtitles on the video playing simultaneously. There should be an option that enables me to do that. Moreover, there should be an option that enables me to adjust the *styling* and *position* of each subtitle separately.

Comment: You could [merge multiple files](http://pas-bien.net/2srt2ass/)... Also, which OS? Price?

Comment: OS: Windows 8.1.
Price: Any.
There's a problem in your _merge multiple files_ solution because of the following reasons: 1. Supports merging up to 2 files only. 2. Takes time and effort. 3. Don't support the merging in-video-file embedded subtitles with other subtitles.

Comment: [3 Ways to Add Two or More Subtitles to Video](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-add-two-or-more-subtitles-to-avi-video/)

Answer (score 1):

[Bomi](https://bomi-player.github.io/downloads.html) claims:

> Enhanced subtitle handling bomi supports various subtitle formats.
>   bomi can render multiple subtitle files at the same time. bomi also
>   can render styled subtitles such as SAMI and ASS format.

[This article](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/playing-two-subtitles-at-the-same-time-in-dvd-player-and-computer/) shows that KMPlayer can show 3 at once.