# Showing multiple videos at once

Tags: open-source, video

Is there any video player that supports *showing multiple videos at once* within the same application window? Image attached as an example for how it could look.

I am a big fan of clean code, and one thing I hate the most is the Singleton-pattern. Having looked at the source code of [VLCJ player](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-player), I noticed that the singleton pattern is being used for the video.

[image: example of how VLC could look if it supported multiple videos within the same window]

There is no requirement for how many videos it should support, just that it should support *more than one*.

As I'm interested in it from a code perspective, I would like it to be open-source. (but if you know of any non-free applications, feel free to mention those as well, as it would tell me that they're not using the singleton pattern). I also don't have a platform requirement.

Comment: Speaking of singleton-pattern, here's something slightly related: [Video player that displays multiple (3 or more) subtitle tracks at once](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/15005/video-player-that-displays-multiple-3-or-more-subtitle-tracks-at-once)

Comment: This can be done with FFmpeg/ffplay on the command line, albeit with a command that looks like spooky black magic. I'm sure there are examples floating around on the SE network of how to do this, i think on the video production site.

Comment: The ffmpeg solution should come in this way, use ffmpeg as streamserver, point vlc to that stream, in ffmpeg command line you will not stream it directly but first processe them with a filter, scale and position with 4 inputs. Doing it realtime with big resolutions could be heavy through..

Answer (score 2):

Other players didn't satisfy my needs so I've created a web-based player:

## Multi Video Player

https://multi-video-player.surge.sh/

[image: screenshot]

### Features

- Unlimited videos (limit is your browser/computer)
- Play/pause, seek, control volume, playback rate for individual or all videos
- Multiple styles - mason (efficient stacking), flat (equally spaced), funnel (decreasing video sizes)
- Zoom in (fewer, larger videos), zoom out (more, smaller videos)
- Multiple play modes - play-single, play-all-muted, play-all, control-all(experimental)
- Intuitive arrow keys & WSAD keys keyboard shortcuts

### Limitations

- Tested only on latest chrome, some issues in FF/Edge, untested in other browsers (safari, all mobile)
- Can only play videos supported by the web browser (mp4/ogg, <strike>flv/avi</strike>). This also makes it depend on the browser to use CPU/GPU for rendering videos. Firefox (at the time of testing) was extremely slow with 10+ videos.
- Depends on Web browser and its File API, can't read/write to disk directly (for example creating playlists, reading entire directories)

Checkout github repo for more:

https://github.com/laggingreflex/multi-video-player

Completely open-source, feel free to fork and/or submit issues/PRs.

Answer (score 2):

Many years too late, but if you're still around (or any future reader) I recommend giving GridPlayer a try, here is the description:

> Simple VLC-based media player that can play multiple videos at the same time. You can play as many videos as you like, the only limit is your hardware. It supports all video formats that VLC supports (which is all of them). You can save your playlist retaining information about the position, sound volume, loops, aspect ratio, etc.

Get it here:
https://github.com/vzhd1701/gridplayer

Comment: This seems very much like what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.awesomevideoplayer.com/

> AVPlayer supports playing multiple videos simultaneously, up to 16 videos at once on each screen! With automatic hardware and software decoding acceleration support. It plays absolutely every video format out there, at lightening fast speed too. Best of all, it’s 100% Free for awesome people like you!

- Free with restrictions (4 simultaneous videos), $14.99 Pro

Answer (score -2):

Not in the same window, But VLC can do multiple instances /

[Bino3d](http://bino3d.org/) is a software made for stereoscopic view, but can also be used for Multiple display for powerwall, VR etc .

That said, I am not really sure why would someone need such a function other than stereoscopic viewer .. ( for the simple user )

For other applications ( Like CCTV or other monitoring ) - these usually come with the hardware and are also hardware specific .

If your aim is a dedicated software with some special function that require a multi-view ,I have wrote myself such software using [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) ( QT ) - that of course depends on thee level and ability of your coding.

Comment: One application is for guards who have to watch multiple cameras for anything funny going on. If you could feed many cameras to one display, then the guards can be looking at any of them, and notice (for instance) motion on one camera.